# LINQ Where data in list variable and list is maybe null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have list contains all value need to be compare to database

```
from staff in this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data
where officeIds.Contains(staff.OfficeId)
```

officeIds has int[] type and officeIds can be null. What should I do if officeIds is null?

I tried

```
where officeIds != null && officeIds.Contains(staff.OfficeId)
```

But it doesn't work. It throws an exception

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity
>   types are supported.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Is there an Exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Then please include it in the question

Comment: @haim770 thank, I just edited it :)

Comment: We need the exception details. Not the fact that there's an exception

Comment: The `officeIds` array is there so that Linq to Entities would be able to emit an SQL `IN(..., ...)` operator, checking for its nullity is not something that the provider is supposed to be doing. You better always initialize `officeIds` to an empty array (`officeIds = new int[]`) or append the `where` clause only after you check for nullity (the latter approach sounds more sensible to me).

Comment: when list is `null` or has no elements (i.e. `officeIds == null || officeIds.Length == 0`), you don't need to execute db query at all because the result set will be empty anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank haim770 suggestion, the below is his comment:

> The officeIds array is there so that Linq to Entities would be able to emit an SQL IN(..., ...) operator, checking for its nullity is not something that the provider is supposed to be doing. 
> You better always initialize officeIds to an empty array (officeIds = new int[]) or append the where clause only after you check for nullity (the latter approach sounds more sensible to me)

The point here we should think out of box rather than focus on how to check null in `where` statement. 
The problem statement:

```
from staff in this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data
where officeIds.Contains(staff.OfficeId)
```

The following `in` accept `IQueryable`. We can check it from outsite of `from`

```
var query = this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data
if(list != null && list.Count > 0)
    query = query.Where("condition")

from staff in query
where *continue other conditions*
select ...
```